# Participant Registration database

Tags: database-design, registration, producer-consumer, database-table

I am working on a database to store information about participants that have enrolled in a program. I made up three tables to store information regarding three types of participants. They are; Transport Operators, Artifacts Producers, and Artifacts Sellers.

The three tables are:

1. TransportOperator (**TransportOperatorID**, FName, LName, *LocationID*, Telephone, OwnerTelepohne, DOB, LicenseNumber, *VehicleModelID*, InsuranceNumber, BusinessLicenseNumber, RoadTaxNumber, PermitNumber, InsuranceNumber, *TransportAssociationID*)
2. Artifact Producer (**ProducerID**, FName, LName, Telephone, *PlaceOfOriginID*, *ProductID*)
3. Artifact Seller (**SellerID**, FName, LName, Telephone, *LanguageID*, *PlaceOfOriginID*, *ProductID*)

*Bold: Primary Key, Italics: Foreign Keys *referenced* to other tables.

Now I am trying to relate these tables to a **Registration** table.

The thing is I don't wana end up having a table that has null Foreign Keys in the registration table as below:

Registration (**RegistrationID**, Date, *ProducerID*, *SellerID*, *TransportOperatorID*)

Should I build three different database or ??

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with null FK's?

Comment: @Pleun, It doesn't look right. Is it ok? I'm sorry, not that experienced in database design.